# CSS Issue with IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I am stuck in Template designing for IE7 and IE8. I cannot bring the result what is intended. For all major browsers, the template looks good and as intended, but there is an issue with IE7 and IE8. I have tested it for all major browsers using http://www.browserstack.com/. The template path is : http://www.directfurnitureplace.co.uk/fofeed/Template1.html.

---

I have tried reducing the font size which solves problem, but I don't want the font size reduced as it displays very small in other browsers (i.e FireFox, Opera, Chrome etc).

I want the in question template to display in IE7 and IE8 as it displays in FireFox and Chrome.

Your help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional stylesheets.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)